# matlab printing splitted plot to file

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm creating a code to do data analysis that will run on a server. The code is supposed to spit a pdf file with 3 plots on it.

I have created a code that generates the plot

```
fig = figure;
for i = 1:3
  %do some calculation to find, X, Y and fit
  subplot(3,1,i)
  scatter(X,Y)
  hold on
  plot(X,fit)
end

print (fig, '-dpdf','fig.pdf')
```

`X`, `Y`, and `fit` are calculated/imported parameters. The output of this code is a pdf document with only the last plot on it (missing the first two).

How can I print all three of them to file?

Comment: I tried your code as-is in a function script and it worked perfectly. I am using Matlab 7.11.0 (R2010b).

Comment: To be precise, I had to add X = rand(1, 10), Y = rand(1, 10), and fit = rand(1, 10) to have data to operate on.  Is it possible that something is wrong with X, Y, or fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code on my CPU (X,Y and fit were generated randomly) and it works fine, so the bug may come from the interaction of this snip of code with you  "%do some calculations block"

I would suggest to add a "hold off" command before the end of the for loop ...

gus

Comment: You are, of course, correct. I had declared a fig aggain inside the loop